# How to have html tags in different lines in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to when enter for example **a*5** , they should be in different lines. By default all 5  tags are in one line:

```
<a href="">1</a><a href="">2</a><a href="">3</a><a href="">4</a><a href="">5</a>
```

But I want this:

```
<a href="">1</a>
<a href="">2</a>
<a href="">3</a>
<a href="">4</a>
<a href="">5</a>
```

**I don't want to use additional extensions** to achieve this goal. I believe VS code has an option for this but I don't remember what was exactly.